# openxlsx: Copying the same style to a new column added to a worksheet

Tags: r, openxlsx

I'm working with the `openxlsx` package and am cloning a worksheet in a workbook object. I then add new data to this cloned worksheet.

How can I apply the same styles to this added data as currently exists on this sheet?

E.g. assume that the old worksheet consists of data in columns 1:3 that was formatted as percentages, has some underlinings, bolding, font sizes etc. I now just want to make sure that the same format/style from column 3 is applied to column 4 (that's where I add my new data).

I found the `getStyle`, `creatStyle` and `replaceStyle` functions in openxlsx, but don't see any option to grab and apply a certain style (because `getStyle` returns a list, but it doesn't tell which list element belongs to which worksheet or column).

My current workflow (although probably not relevant/helpful):

old_wb <- loadWorkbook(file.choose())

```
new_wb <- old_wb
cloneWorksheet(new_wb, "new", "old worksheet")
writeData(new_wb,
          sheet = "new",
          x = c(1:3),
          startRow = 3,
          startCol = 4)

saveWorkbook(new_wb, file = "test.xlsx", overwrite = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use this function which combines the capabilities of the `openxlsx` and `tidyxl` packages. It will give you the style objects associated with all cells in a given excel, as well as all other content like numeric, character and formulas. You can then directly apply the style to other cells or in a different workbook.

```
read_excel_template <- function(excel_path) {
   cells <- tidyxl::xlsx_cells(excel_path)
   template <- openxlsx::loadWorkbook(excel_path)
   
   map_df(.x = enframe(template$styleObjects)$value, 
                   .f = ~ tibble(
                     style = c(.x$style),
                     sheet = .x$sheet,
                     row = .x$rows,
                     col = .x$cols
                   )) %>% 
      full_join(cells, by=c("sheet", "row", "col")) %>% 
      relocate(style, .after = address)
}
```

Comment: This looks very promising, but can you also add an example of how one uses the result of your function to write a new file including the styles from the previous, older workbook?

Comment: the style column contains the styles as an object. You can filter the dataframe by the `row` and `col` columns to get the style you want to copy, and then provide that style to `addStyle()`

Answer (score 1):

From studying @Ljupcho Naumov's great answer, I learned that if you simply want the cell locations of the styles from `openxlsx::getStyle` then you can use

```
old_wb$styleObjects
```

which returns a list of the styles as well as the sheet/rows/columns.  You can check that the style objects are the same with

```
all.equal(purrr::map(old_wb$styleObjects, "style"), getStyles(old_wb))
```

Comment: Thanks, but I struggle in seeing how this could help in my use case of copying over a certain style to another column.

Comment: Yes, the more I think about it, the more I like Ljupcho Naumov's answer.  It gives you, for each row and column, the style that you can apply.  If an entire column has the same style, then you could just look at the first row of data, and for each column take the style.  Then apply to all cells that you write in the new workbook.  But if the styles were using some manual logic (for example, negative numbers are red) then I don't see how you could automatically apply that logic.

Answer (score 1):

This is one of the many things improved in `openxlsx2`. In the upcoming release 0.3 you can simply run the following code. This will load a workbook, get the styles from a range of cells. Clone the worksheet, apply the style to a range of cells, add data and open the sheet.

```r
library(openxlsx2)

wb <- wb_load(system.file("extdata", "oxlsx2_sheet.xlsx", package = "openxlsx2"))
styles <- wb_get_cell_style(wb = wb, dims = "A12:G15")

wb <- wb %>% 
  wb_clone_worksheet(new = "Clone1") %>% 
  wb_set_cell_style(dims = "A22:G25", style = styles) %>% 
  wb_add_data(x = matrix(1, 1, 5), dims = "B22:G22", colNames = FALSE) %>%
  wb_open() # or wb_save("file.xlsx")
```

In `openxlsx2` there are no style objects. Therefore the styles of imported xlsx workbook are untouched when modifying the workbook. While you asked to clone a sheet, that's improved as well. It's now even possible to clone sheets with charts and pivot tables (lacking slider support).

Answer (score 0):

The getStyles() function returns just the list of style objects present in the workbook, not location of where styles are used. It also orders the styles and can be viewed using `getStyles(wb) %>% View()`

If you would want to apply an existing style after writing the new column you would have to add the style to that column with `addStyle()`. You could use the getStyle() though to easily pull over styles and layer them as well.

Below I have 4 styles. Note the the big_purple_text will ultimately be the fourth style listed once the workbook is loaded. I apply these 4 styles to the columns in the iris data set. Save it. And then load it as iris_wb.

```
library(openxlsx)
wb <- createWorkbook()
bold_blue_text <- createStyle(textDecoration = "bold", fontColour = "blue")
red_italic_text <- createStyle(textDecoration = "italic", fontColour = "red")
big_purple_text <- createStyle(fontSize = 18, fontColour = "purple")
underline_text <- createStyle(textDecoration = "underline")
addWorksheet(wb, "Iris")
writeData(wb, "Iris", iris)

addStyle(wb, "Iris", bold_blue_text, cols = 1, rows = 1:dim(iris)[1],gridExpand = TRUE)
addStyle(wb, "Iris", red_italic_text, cols = 2, rows = 1:dim(iris)[1],gridExpand = TRUE)
addStyle(wb, "Iris", big_purple_text, cols = 3:4, rows = 1:dim(iris)[1],gridExpand = TRUE)
addStyle(wb, "Iris", underline_text, cols = 5, rows = 1:dim(iris)[1],gridExpand = TRUE)

saveWorkbook(wb, file = "C:\\Users\\Desktop\\test.xlsx", overwrite = TRUE)

openXL(wb)

iris_wb <- loadWorkbook("C:\\Users\\Desktop\\test.xlsx")
```

This will show only the 4 styles loaded, using View you can explore more how the ordering of the styles are listed

```
getStyles(iris_wb)

getStyles(iris_wb) %>% View() #Here you can view the ascending order of the style types, note that the fontdecoration is above fontsize. This is why big_purple_text is listed 4th

#Write new data to existing sheet
writeData(iris_wb, "Iris", mtcars, startCol = 6)

#add styles from existing styles in loaded workbook
addStyle(iris_wb, "Iris", getStyles(iris_wb)[[1]], cols = 6, rows = 1:10)
addStyle(iris_wb, "Iris", getStyles(iris_wb)[[3]], cols = 7:8, rows = 1:20, gridExpand = TRUE)
addStyle(iris_wb, "Iris", getStyles(iris_wb)[[4]], cols = 8:10, rows = 10:20, gridExpand = TRUE, stack = TRUE) # Should retain underline
openXL(iris_wb)
```

Comment: Thanks, but this is exactly my problem. I need to know which style does what without having to inspect them. I have 162 styles in the workbook and can't test them all. So if there is no way of figurring out which styles apply to a certain sheet/column range, I don't think this will work. I checked with the developer of the package and there might be a "format painter" feature in the future which would probably be my best bet then.

Comment: ah I see. You only mention 4 columns in your post so didn't know you couldn't look at the number of styles present with getStyles(). Maybe modify your question to include that element. Is it always column 3 that you'd want to 'format paint' that column's styles to other columns? Wouldn't be the best work around, but if a certain column you want to replicate, you could isolate out that single column as own workbook, getStyles() from that one column workbook and copy over?

Comment: Ah, that makes me thinking...so yes, just looking at all present styles won't work because I have so many of them. But this other idea of isolating the column from which I want to grab the style, could work. This depends on openxlsx, though, and if it preserves styles when I cut a sheet/workbook into smaller pieces. I will try.

Comment: Closing the loop here that this idea probably doesn't work. So I can reduce my WB to just the one sheet I want to edit and get the styles from that one sheet (reduces it from 162 to 25), but I still can't narrow it done to just the styling from the one required column in order to apply it to a new column. Although I can `deleteData` from a sheet which is also supposed to delete the styling (but seems to be buggy, because the styles are kept in the WB), I can#t just get this one-column style.