# both read and write excel formats in R

Tags: excel, formatting, xlsx, openxlsx

I'm trying to read an excel file including formatting (cell and text colour, bold, ...) to R, do some editings in the data, and then write it back to excel, including the original formatting. So far, I found R packages to write excel files including formating (openxlsx, xlsx), and also a package which reads excel format (tidyxl). However, I didn't find an easy way to write an excel file with the same formatting that has been read by the R function.

I.e.: the way that tidyxl gathers the format data in an R object is totally different than how openxlsx or xlsx writes it to excel format.

I wonder if anyone knows of something or developed any easy function for this.

Comment: `openxlsx` should be able to do that, depending on the complexity of the xlsx file. Import some xlsx file as workbook, modify it and save the workbook. For examples see: [here](https://ycphs.github.io/openxlsx/articles/Introduction.html#gallery=)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [openxlsx: Copying the same style to a new column added to a worksheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70754569/openxlsx-copying-the-same-style-to-a-new-column-added-to-a-worksheet)